# How to structure the PDF-related code so that it is not in routes file?

Tags: laravel, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy

I'm using the Laravel Snappy PDF package [barryvdh/laravel-snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)

It's all working perfectly, however the routes file now has a lot of information that I'd like to clean out of the routes file and put somewhere else.

```
Route::get('services/{service}/overview', function ($id) {
    $service = \App\Service::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    $service->load('sbo_name', 'sbm_name', 'stm_name', 'get_lifecycle_status', 'items', 'environments', 'agreements', 'supported_services', 'required_services', 'serviceDependencies', 'readiness');
    $data['service'] = $service->toArray();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.services.overview', $data)
        ->setPaper('a4')
        ->setOrientation('portrait')
        ->setOption('footer-right', 'Page [page] of [toPage]     ')
        ->setOption('footer-left', '     Printed: [date]')
        ->setOption('footer-font-size', 8)
        ->setOption('footer-font-name', 'Arial')
        ->setOption('margin-top', 10)
        ->setOption('margin-left', 5)
        ->setOption('margin-right', 5)
        ->setOption('lowquality', false)
        ->setOption('dpi', 96)
        ->setOption('image-quality', 100);
    return $pdf->inline('Service Overview.pdf');
});
```

What's the best way to structure this?  I don't want to repeat the pdf options for each new report either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, clean up your route files by moving them into a controller.

`Route::get('services/{service}/overview', ExportServiceController@show);`

```
// app/Http/Controllers/ExportServiceController.php
class ExportServiceController extends Controller

public function show($id) {
    return (new App/ExportServicePdf)->execute($id);

}
```

Further clean up your controller by moving the logic into its own class so it's reusable in other controller.

```
// for example app/ExportServicePdf.php
namespace App;

class ExportServicePdf 
{
   public function execute($id) 
   {
    $service = \App\Service::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    $service->load('sbo_name', 'sbm_name', 'stm_name', 'get_lifecycle_status', 'items', 'environments', 'agreements', 'supported_services', 'required_services', 'serviceDependencies', 'readiness');
    $data['service'] = $service->toArray();

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.services.overview', $data)
    ->setPaper('a4')
    ->setOrientation('portrait')
    ->setOption('footer-right', 'Page [page] of [toPage]     ')
    ->setOption('footer-left', '     Printed: [date]')
    ->setOption('footer-font-size', 8)
    ->setOption('footer-font-name', 'Arial')
    ->setOption('margin-top', 10)
    ->setOption('margin-left', 5)
    ->setOption('margin-right', 5)
    ->setOption('lowquality', false)
    ->setOption('dpi', 96)
    ->setOption('image-quality', 100);
     return $pdf->inline('Service Overview.pdf');
   }

}
```

A quick dig into the library, there's a public method [`setOptions()`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/blob/master/src/PdfWrapper.php) which accepts an array of options.

In your `ExportServicePdf` class, you can further refactor it to:

```
class ExportServicePdf
{
   private $options = [
      'footer-font-size' => 8,
      'footer-font-name' => 'Arial',
      //...
    ];

    // Then you can do 
    public function execute($id)
    {
       $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.services.overview', $data)
             ->setPaper('a4')
             ->setOrientation('portrait')
             ->setOptions($this->options)
    }

}
```